# Xamarin Forms - using the equivalent of TranslateTo in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

If I want to move a button up the screen the same distance as the height of another control on the page I can do this:

```
this.myControl.TranslateTo(20, - this.myOtherControl.Height);
```

Is there a way to do this in XAML?

Comment: Have you looked into the use of RelativeLayout’s?

Answer (score 0):

Is your situation  like the screenshot below?

[image]

Do you want to achieve it like this screenshot?

[image]

You could used `TranslationY="{ Binding Path=TranslationY ,Source={x:Reference btn1}}"` to achieve that.

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  VerticalOptions="Start">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HeightRequest="100"    Padding="20,0,0,0">
        <Button x:Name="btn1"  Text="Aqua" HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="50" TranslationY="23" />
     </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HeightRequest="100"    Padding="20,0,0,0">
        <Button HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="50" Text="llll" TranslationY="{ Binding Path=TranslationY ,Source={x:Reference btn1}}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```